# how to make skin settings in dotnetnuke?

Tags: asp.net

i installed dotnetnuke in my system, installation is completed successfully, now i want to change skin settings according to my requirement like changing colors,font,logs like that can u help me how can i do this in dotnetnuke. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should familiarize yourself with how to create and edit DNN skins.

A good start would be here http://www.packtpub.com/article/dotnetnuke-skinning-creating-first-skin